# Relation of floats to section/subsection breaks

Tags: floats

I'm writing a book, and an irritating but recurring thing I encounter is the placement of a float *after* the section header for the section following the one where I wrote it to be.  It seems better to my way of thinking to put the float at the top of the page, then begin the section.  Instead, the (new) section begins, perhaps with only a few lines on the old page, and the float is plopped down in the middle of a discussion about something else.  An extreme example, which occurs too often, is to have the new section header at the bottom of the page, then the section text begins at the top of the next page, with the float---from the previous section---in the middle of the page.  I have Mittelbach's 2014 article, but a quick skim did not reveal anything relevant to this issue.

Comment: latex never breaks a page after a section heading unless you are using some very non standard definitions of your headings. Please post a small but complete example, it is hard to debug code we can not see.

Comment: also if floats are moved to a later page they are never inserted mid page on a text page, only at the top or bottom so it is hard to guess what you mean by "with only a few lines on the old page, and the float is plopped down in the middle of a discussion about something else"